# Añadir una cadena antes de un incremental

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
with open(ruta, "a+") as fichero_fecha:
    fecha_actual = datetime.now()
    if fichero_fecha.tell():
        fichero_fecha.seek(0)
        fecha = datetime.strptime(next(fichero_fecha).rstrip(), "%Y/%m/%d")
        cont = int(next(fichero_fecha).split(".")[0])
        if (fecha_actual - fecha).days > 1:
            fichero_fecha.seek(0)
            fichero_fecha.truncate()
            fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\n')
            fichero_fecha.write(f'{cont + 1}.txt\n')
    else:
        fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\n1.txt\n')
```

Este código me genera dentro de un fichero la siguiente estructura (el número va incrementando):

> 2020/06/03
>
> 1.txt

Como puedo hacer que tenga la siguiente estructura:

> 2020/06/03
>
> Hola1.txt

Seguiría siendo igual, solo incrementaría el número "Hola2.txt", "Hola3.txt", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que modificar los literales de cadena formateados que se encargan de generar la segunda linea:

```
fichero_fecha.write(f'Hola{cont + 1}.txt\n')
#                     ^^^^
#                     ^^^^
```

y

```
fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\nHola1.txt\n') 
#                                                          ^^^^
#                                                          ^^^^
```

Ten en cuenta que en un f'string solo el código encerrado entre `{}` (diana de reemplazo) es evaluado, el resto se considera un literal de cadena sin más:

> ```
> >>> f"7 + 3 es {7 + 3} y 'Python' tiene {len('Python')} letras."
>
> "7 + 3 es 10 y 'Python' tiene 6 letras."
> ```

El segundo problema es el parseo de la linea para extraer el contador, puedes usar un simple slicing:

```
 cont = int(next(fichero_fecha)[4:-5])
```

tus lineas serán de la forma:

> "Hola1.txt\n"
>      "Hola2356.txt\n"

el rebanado `[4: -5]` indica que se tome desde el quinto item  contando desde el principio (recordar que se indiza desde 0) hasta el quinto por la cola.

> ```
> >>> "Hola1.txt\n"[4: -5]
> '1'
> >>> "Hola2356.txt\n"[4: -5]
> '2356'
> ```

Obviamente, si modificas la cadena en un futuro deberás modificar el rebanado de forma acorde:

> ```
> >>> "HolaSoEs1.text\n"[8: -6]
> '1'
> ```

La fórmula general es:

```
[len(prefijo): -len(sufijo) + 1]
```

Es decir:

```
with open(ruta, "a+") as fichero_fecha:
    fecha_actual = datetime.now()
    if fichero_fecha.tell():
        fichero_fecha.seek(0)
        fecha = datetime.strptime(next(fichero_fecha).rstrip(), "%Y/%m/%d")
        cont = int(next(fichero_fecha)[4:-5])
        if (fecha_actual - fecha).days > 1:
            fichero_fecha.seek(0)
            fichero_fecha.truncate()
            fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\n')
            fichero_fecha.write(f'Hola{cont + 1}.txt\n')
    else:
        fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\nHola1.txt\n')
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que tenía hecho. Pero a la hora de ejecutar de nuevo el comando por segunda vez se me imprime por pantalla el mensaje: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Hola1'". Creo que esto es debido al split que no lo hace correctamente.

Comment: De nuevo, muchas gracias, ya lo entendí a la perfección.

Comment: Es cierto, no recordaba la función, ahora mismo tramito las aceptaciones, gracias.